# One-shot collection of shoujo manga, including a story about Tarzan-like jungle man and a girl who sacrificed herself for him

Tags: story-identification, manga, anthology-book

I've been craving to reread this one-shot shoujo manga collection. I only remember several things from this manga, since I read it a long ago.

The first story is in space universe. The next story is about a man who lived in jungle since he was born (I guess?) who meets a newcomer girl; kinda Tarzan-y thing. The man can't speak a single human word, but he spoke something when the girl died in his arms to shield him from a gunshot. The other story I remember (only a glimpse) is about a girl who played the guitar (?) and has an unrequited love (?); I think it has café setting.

It's a very old manga. I think I read it in 2005-ish.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall any more details of the other stories?  Is there anything about the art that stood out?  (Character depictions, significant locations?)